Is there an image editing software for PC that allows infinitely zooming in/out?
I'm trying to make something called an "Infinite Zoom Art", and I've already made 34 images (.svg files) using Inkscape. However, I need an app that has an infinite canvas, but at the same time allows importing SVGs.
I tried using JavaScript along with HTML and CSS in VSCode, but after some scrolling, it gets really buggy because of the huge numbers. The images start falshing and turning black, and it would be far too dificult to solve. I'm just asking if there's an app that allows me to make this 2D "game", because I tried everything but I just couldn't find one that has both of these features.

What do you mean by "infinitely"? Any example of how it should look? As normally after certain zoom you'd be just moving into a single colored pixel more and more for no reason

@Destroy666 OP is talking about vector graphics, so the internal representation of the image is not made up of pixels and can theoretically be rendered at arbitrary (finite) zoom levels without a problem.

@paleonix yes, my message wasn't too accurate, I meant pixel rendered in the software UI. I still don't quite get the need of infinitely zooming those. Is  it some kind of weird looping?

@Destroy666 I don't know what exactly OP is trying to achieve, but the problem might be that such an implementation would need arbitrary precision arithmetic as well to be able to render these arbitrary zoom levels (similar to Mandelbrot zooms). And any ordinary vector graphics software will just use ordinary 32 bit or 64 bit arithmetic for acceptable real-time performance.

@Destroy666 If you just search "Infinite Zoom" on YT, you'll see a bunch of examples. Basically I want to put these SVG files together to make a huge drawing which won't be pixelated after scaling. The problem is that each image is supposed to be at least about 1000x smaller than the previous image, which as I said obviously results in massive numbers very quickly. So I'm trying to either find an image editing software that has an unlimited canvas, or find a different solution. I just can't think of any.

I'm not too sure where you got the idea that any of these videos uses "infinite zoom". Seems much simplier with not too hard video editing. Bunch of them actually explain a similar process  in the description, with raster graphics even.

@Destroy666 I'm not trying to make a video, I'm trying to make the drawing itself. By the way most of those people are using the well known Endless Paper app, but that's only for IOS. I only mentioned the videos as an example of what I'm trying to make.
